# Define a navigation case in faces-config.xml to do page reload on a certain outcome?

Tags: jsf, navigation, reload, faces-config

I want to define a navigation case in faces-config.xml to do a page reload/refresh, without navigating to another page on certain outcome from any  view id. How do I define it in faces-config.xml as I dont have any specific `to-viewId` to hardcode in faces-config.xml ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to reload the existing page. In which case, viewId = #{view.viewId} ?

Comment: yes I want to reload just the current page. I'll try out your solution! So, it's possible to put ELs in `faces-config` ?! Didn't know this!

Comment: yes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxf.html and http://java.dzone.com/articles/fluent-navigation-jsf-2

Comment: Thanks please post as an answer so I could accept. `#{view.viewId}` didn't work for me as I use a URL rewritter(Prettyfaces) but I found a solution once I came to know I could use EL over there. Another thing, there is small issue if you could help, my URLs are extensionless, `topic/23423` & faces-config redirects me to `topic/23423.xhtml` by appending `.xhtml` at the end of my viewIds. How could I prevent adding `.xhtml` to my extensionless URLs ?

Comment: OP has posted followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978988/prevent-xhtml-append-to-to-view-id-within-faces-config-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EL` expressions in your `faces-config.xml` file.

To return to the current view, for example:

```
<navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>#{view.viewId}</to-view-id>
 </navigation-case>
```