# Prevent ".xhtml" append to "to-view-Id" within faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, faces-config

How do I keep extensionless URL in the `to-view-id`(s) within faces-config.xml so that it doesn't append `.xhtml` to the end of it ?

For e.g. while defining a navigation case, I define a `to-view-id` as `/topics/54233` but faces-config redirects me to `/topics/54233.xhtml` which I surely want to prevent. How do I do it ?

Comment: What's the physical file here? `54233.xhtml`? Or `topics.xhtml`?

Comment: physical file is neither `topics.xhtml` nor `54233.xhtml`. It is actually `viewChannel.xhtml`. `54233` is just an id of one of the topics for which this page is shown.

Comment: Have you thought about an url rewriting tool as prettyfaces?

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Yeah I already rewrite my URLs using prettyfaces, also I'm aware that there exists Prettyfaces navigation techniques but I can't work with Prettyfaces for navigation(as it doesn't allow different navigation cases for same outcome based on different `from-view-id`(s) as offered by `faces-config.xml`) rather I'm trying to keep that job with faces-config.xml
.

Comment: As far as I know, if you use a JSF navigation case with Prettyfaces filter declared, PF should prettify your target url (keep in mind PF works with POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, should it should take care of doing that conversion).

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: As specified in the question, I write mention this `/topics/54233` as `to-view-id` within faces-config, now this is not a real url but just a url pattern identifable by PF, but faces-config.xml just converts this to `/topics/54233.xhtml` & make the browser ask for this invalid file.

Comment: Are extensionless URLs configured via OmniFaces FacesViews or via PrettyFaces? At least, they have never been intented to be mixable, so it might happen that there's some conflict somewhere.

Comment: @BalusC: they are configured via prettyfaces. Some of them are like `/topics` for `/topics/index.xhtml` without anything like prettyfaces/omnifaces.

Comment: Okay, I got confused by presence of `[omnifaces]` tag which suggests that you were using extensionless URLs via its FacesViews feature. I removed the tag. Sorry, can't help you here as I've never really used PrettyFaces. I however recall having read about something like a `pretty:` prefix in navigation case outcomes. Perhaps you need that in this specific case?

Comment: Thanks BalusC! Actually I put the omnifaces tag as I thought it was a general issue, related to preventing .xhtml append by jsf, so thought may be relevant to both prettyfaces as well as omnifaces,  as both give out extensionless urls.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: I installed prettyfaces in my JSF app following this doc[http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/#section-4]. It doesn't tell me to define a pretty filter in `web.xml`. But when I attempted to add a filter as guided by another prettyfaces version guide, I got `ClassNotFoundException: com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Could you please indicate if I'm missing something here?